Find $\lim(n^2x_n)$ if $x_{n+1} = \dfrac{n(n+1)x_n}{n^3x_n+x_n^2+n^2},\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*$
Let $(x_n)$ be determined by $x_1=1,x_{n+1} = \dfrac{n(n+1)x_n}{n^3x_n+x_n^2+n^2},\forall n \in 
\mathbb{N}^*$. Find $\lim(n^2x_n)$.
My idea was to use Weierstrass theory by putting $y_n=n^2x_n,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*$
Then I have to find the bound of $y_n$ and show it is increasing or decreasing
But $y_{n+1}-y_n=nx_n\left(\dfrac{(n+1)^3}{n^3x_n+x_n^2+n^2}-n\right)$
And I can't showing this $\left(\dfrac{(n+1)^3}{n^3x_n+x_n^2+n^2}-n\right)$ greater than $0$ or less than $0$
And it is harder when try to find a bound
Can anyone help me please? Thank you a lots!

1/ Did you mean $y_n = x^2 x_n$? Based on the rest, that seems to be the case $\quad$ 2/ Did you check the first 20 values or so to see if your hypothesis of "increasing or decreasing" holds?

I have edited that, is my prediction correct? Thanks

See my question 2. My guess is that you have not done so.

Since numerical simulation suggests the limit is $3$, study $z_n:=n^2x_n-3$. I expect you'll find it's asymptotic to $c/n$ for some constant $c$.

It's quite straightforward by the reciprocal trick.
Let $y_n=\frac{n}{x_n}$ (this is for cancelling the $n+1$), so we have $\frac{n+1}{y_n}=\frac{n^2(n+1)/y_n}{n^4/y_n+n^2/y_n^2+n^2}$.
Rearranging the terms and take the reciprocals on both sides we have $y_{n+1}=y_n+n^2+\frac{1}{y_n}$.
We can see that $x_n<\frac{n+1}{n^2}$, thus $\frac{1}{y_n}=\frac{x_n}{n}\le\frac{n+1}{n^3}$. So we have $y_n=y_1+(1^2+2^2+\dots+(n-1)^2)+\frac{1}{y_1}+\dots+\frac{1}{y_n}=\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}+O(1)$. So we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^3/y_n=3$.
In fact, by the derivation above, you can have $x_n=\frac{3}{n^2}+\frac{9}{2n^3}+\frac{21}{4n^4}+O(\frac{1}{n^5})$.
